# Resque - Getting response after worker has finished job

Tags: redis, resque

I am using php-resque for specifics, but I suppose I am looking for a conceptual answer, and so php/ruby differences shouldn't be an issue.

Let's say I add a job to Resque that asks a worker process to retrieve some data from a MySQL database. The server making the request does not have direct access to the database, so rather it uses Resque to make this request. How can I pass the database response back to the script which called it?

From what I read, it seems the worker would have to store that data in Redis, and then my script would just have to access it from there. I'm thinking after I enqueue the job, my script simply waits until the worker finishes, by tracking it according to its id. Does this logic make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that immediately comes to mind is to setup [web-hooks](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/what-are-webhooks-and-how-do-they-enable-real-time-web/2012/01/30) and to use them once resque completes the job. This will not send the response the original caller, but thats probably not what you really want to do because it will cause [blocking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jvmc3/index.html).

Comment: So the issue with this is that the calling script needs to do additional functions depending on what the worker response is. I am under the impression that a webhook would invoke a brand new session of the script, correct?

Comment: Yes it will be a new session, but resque can take several seconds or even minutes depending on your environment and how busy it is. If this as not a problem you might consider using [async/await](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.async.php)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm thinking though my best bet is to have the worker save the response in redis, and do something like:
`
while(job not done) -->
  if(job done) -->
    query redis for response
`